# Return multiple rows containing a MAX value using SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a SQLite3 table called `Player_Plays_In` with the following relation:

`Player_Plays_In(player_id, match_id, position, points_scored)`. `player_id` and `match_id` together are the primary key. Some sample data from the table looks like this:

[image: sample data.]

I need to find the player_id with the most points scored. A given `player_id` will appear multiple times in the table, once for each match they play in. I can sum the points by `player_id` using `GROUP BY` and can find ***a*** max with the following query:

```
SELECT ID, MAX( points ) 
FROM (
      SELECT player_plays_in.player_id AS ID, 
          SUM(player_plays_in.points_scored) AS points
      FROM player_plays_in
      WHERE player_plays_in.points_scored > 0
      GROUP BY player_plays_in.player_id
      );
```

But this only returns the first instance of ID, MAX( points ).

[image: Single row being returned]

That is, I know there are three separate players all of whom have scored 30 points. The query is only returning the first one. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a CTE and subquery:

```
with p as (
      SELECT ppi.player_id AS ID, SUM(ppi.points_scored) AS points
      FROM player_plays_in ppi
      WHERE ppi.points_scored > 0
      GROUP BY ppi.player_id
     )
select p.*
from p
where p.points = (select max(p2.points) from p p2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT ID, Points 
FROM (
      SELECT player_plays_in.player_id AS ID, 
          SUM(player_plays_in.points_scored) AS points
      FROM player_plays_in
      WHERE player_plays_in.points_scored > 0
      GROUP BY player_plays_in.player_id
      ) AS D
WHERE Points = (SELECT MAX( points ) 
    FROM (
          SELECT player_plays_in.player_id AS ID, 
              SUM(player_plays_in.points_scored) AS points
          FROM player_plays_in
          WHERE player_plays_in.points_scored > 0
          GROUP BY player_plays_in.player_id
          ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Appreciate the help. Both Gordon Linoff's and DineshDB's suggestions worked. I was able to get it working last night with this:

```
SELECT player_plays_in.player_id, SUM( player_plays_in.points_scored) AS 
    TotalPoints
FROM player_plays_in 
GROUP BY player_plays_in.player_id 
HAVING TotalPoints = ( SELECT MAX( points ) 
                       FROM ( SELECT SUM( player_plays_in.points_scored) AS 
                                     points
                              FROM player_plays_in
                              WHERE player_plays_in.points_scored > 0
                              GROUP BY player_plays_in.player_id
                            )
                      );
```